# get length of character matching between two string in R

Tags: r, string, string-comparison

I have a dataframe where i need to compare two columns and find the number of matching characters between two elements.

For eg: x and y are two elements to be compared which look like below:

```
x<- "1/2"
y<-"2/3"
```

I did unlisted and splitted them by '/' as below:

```
unlist(strsplit(x,"/"))->a
unlist(strsplit(y,"/"))->b
```

Then i used pmatch:

```
pmatch(a,b,nomatch =0)
[1] 0 1
```

Used sum() to know how many characters are matching:

```
sum(pmatch(a,b,nomatch =0))
[1] 1
```

However, when the comparison is done the other way:

```
 pmatch(b,a,nomatch = 0)
 [1] 2 0
```

Since there is only one match between the two string, why is it showing 2. It could be index. But i would need to get how many characters are same between the strings irrespective of the comparison a vs b or b vs a.

Could someone help how to get this.

Comment: Read up on `?pmatch`, specifically the return value - it's an integer vector giving the indices of the elements in table which matched. So instead of summing, try `length(pmatch(a,b))`

Comment: Maybe: `length(intersect(a, b))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per `?pmatch`, `pmatch` seeks matches for the elements of its first argument among those of its second.

For example, "2" in the first list matches the second element in the second list.

```
> pmatch(c("2", "1"),c("3","2"),nomatch =0)
# [1] 2 0
```

One way to know the number of elements got matched is to sum non-zero elements:

```
sum(pmatch(c("2", "1"),c("3","2"),nomatch =0) != 0)
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
sum(pmatch(b, a, nomatch = 0) != 0)    # 1
sum(pmatch(a, b, nomatch = 0) != 0)    # 1
```

return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be

```
sum(b %in% a)
[1] 1
sum(a %in% b)
[1] 1
```